# Need clarification about the recommended way of bootstrapping a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In the Java Docs for [`SpringApplication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html), it is mentioned that:

> `SpringApplication`s can read beans from a variety of different
>   sources. It is generally recommended that a single `@Configuration`
>   class is used to bootstrap your application [...]

Does this statement mean that it is recommended for an app to ***only have one `@Configuration` class***, or is it saying that it is recommended to pass a class that has been annotated with `@Configuration` to `SpringApplication` (e.g. to its `run` method) -- without putting any limitations on the number of `@Configuration` classes?

Also I find the rest of the statement difficult to interpret:

> [...] however, any of the following sources can also be used:
>
> - `Class` - A Java class to be loaded by `AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader`
> - `Resource` - An XML resource to be loaded by `XmlBeanDefinitionReader`, or a groovy script to be loaded by
>     `GroovyBeanDefinitionReader`
> - `Package` - A Java package to be scanned by `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner`
> - `CharSequence` - A class name, resource handle or package name to loaded as appropriate. If the `CharSequence` cannot be resolved to
>     class and does not resolve to a `Resource` that exists it will be
>     considered a `Package`.

While I have used `SpringApplication.run` before without any problems, now reading its JavaDocs description has me totally confused.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand it :

> a single @Configuration class is used to bootstrap your application

You should have one @Configuration class that is the root configuration of your application.

This makes the config much easier to understand and to debug.
For sure you can use @Import to import other configurations.

In reality you may have different root configrations for tests and for prod. But you will use always only one as the starting point.

> however, any of the following sources can also be used:

That part describes which type of sources can be used to create the application context. These sources can be passed to the constructor :

```
public SpringApplication(Object... sources)
```

or a setter :

```
public void setSources(Set<Object> sources)
```

- Class - a class annotated with @Configuration
- Resource - a xml file with spring configuration
- Package - a package that will be scanned to find configurations
- CharSequence - a string with the name of a class or package. This allows e.g. to use configuration classes, that are not available at compile time.

I personally have never configured a SpringApplication providing the sources to the constructor or setter. I have one root configuration and   annotate my SpringApplication class with @Import.

Answer (score 0):

When you using  `@SpringApplication` or `@EnableAutoConfiguration` spring boot will `automatically configure your Spring application based on the jar dependencies that you have added`

and it should be used just once in your application , On another hand `@Configuration` it could be used as many as needed in same root where `@SpringApplication` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Spring recommended to have just One primary `@Configuration` that add `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

you can include and exclude as many as you need `@Configuration`s to the Primary `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html#using-boot-auto-configuration

from my understanding `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and  `@SpringApplication` almost have same job